# How can i make sound on and off using my native iPhone Application?

Tags: ios4, mpvolumeview

I want to make sound On and Off thru my Native iPhone Application so please give me some suggestion for doing that.It's only up to my Native application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aiming for Mute on and Off ?

Refer this thread for more info if you are aiming for it

[Is it possible to programmatically mute the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596862/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-mute-the-iphone)