# Programmatically mute the iPhone ringer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to programmatically mute the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596862/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-mute-the-iphone)

Is it possible to programmatically mute the iPhone ringer in a way that Apple won't reject the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you are not concerned about Apple's approval, then you can do with with [AVSystemController](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/source/browse/trunk/include/include/Celestial/AVSystemController.h?r=136)