# Is there any alternate solution to mute ringer programmatically?

Tags: iphone, xcode6.1, ios8.1, audiotoolbox, avsystemcontroller

I'm working on an iphone application which used to mute the phone ringer programmatically.Currently I'm using celestial.framework to mute,but I come across that the apple will reject using private framework.Please anybody give right solution to achieve it.I'm new to iOS development.Thanks

```
Class avSystemControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVSystemController");
NSString *soundCategory = @"Ringtone";
float newVolumeLevel = 0.0;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10371312/1489823 http://stackoverflow.com/q/596862/1489823

Comment: So, Is there alternate solution to achieve it....I found this app on app store http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8